# Scraping data from input value

Tags: javascript, iframe, web-scraping

there is website which has:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-6"><strong><input type="text" class="no-style" value="John"></strong></div>
  Last name: <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-6"><strong><input type="text" class="no-style" value="Miller"></strong></div>
  Email: <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-6"><strong><input type="text" class="no-style" value="j.miller@gmail.com"></strong></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to scrape data from input value (John, Miller, j.miller@gmail.com) and show it in my page (maybe putting that site into iframe and scrape from it?) or maybe using something like:

```
// Get HTML from page
$.get( 'http://example.com/', function( html ) {

    // Loop through elements you want to scrape content from
    $(html).find("ul").find("li").each( function(){

        var text = $(this).text();
        // Do something with content

    } )

} );
```

I don't know. I am not good with javascript. And there is bonus: input values on every refresh are different. Can I extract somehow data from 100 refresh or something? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

i will assume that you need to get the data from the input element and then use it somewhere else in your site

you could easily do so using the jquery [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) function

here is some sample code

```
<form id="my-form">
  name: <input type="text" id='test-input'/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
  var input;
  $('#my-form').on('submit', function() {
    input = $('#test-input').val();
  });
</script>
```

you could then use the variable anyway you want, whether it is to cache data or for improving user experience

Answer (score 0):

Get the value and `var _value = $('#elementId').val();` and use it anywhere on the page `$('#elementID').val(_value);` or `$('selector').text(_value);`